# typescript sub class constructor different parameters

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I stumbled today and I'm not super sure why TS allows creating of subclasses with different parameters for the constructor

```js
class C1 {
  constructor (protected foo: number[] = []){}
}
class C2 extends C1 {
  constructor (protected bar: number){ // why not alert here?
    super()
  }
}
```

Comment: you can have whatever you like in the constructor, as long as you call `super(...args)`... what do you think should happend?

Comment: @Ric i would assume that this breaks as i can not create a subclass of C1 in this case C2 with the same parameters. that just seems strange to me. i would have assumed that the constructors would need to have the same call structure

Comment: Your c'tor in `C1` has a default value set, so calling `super()` allows this to take place. Of course, you can add to the c'tor in `C2`: `(bar: number, foo: number[])`

Answer (score 0):

This is the behavior most Object Oriented programming languages have. So allowing for a child class to have different input parameters than its parent is intended. The consistency with the base class is fostered by the super call.

***Aside:*** *But maybe classes are not really what you want in your case? Here's another pattern that might be better suited for your context. It allows to enforce consistent constructor parameters:*

```
type YourThing = {
  someProp: "prop"
  someFn: () => void
  someGetter: () => "A" | "B"
}

type CommonParams = "CommonParams"
type ThingBuilder = (params: CommonParams) => YourThing

const builderOne: ThingBuilder = params => {
  let privateMutableThing: "A" | "B" = "A"

  return {
    someProp: "prop",
    someFn: () => {
      if (privateMutableThing === "A") {
        privateMutableThing = "B"
      }
    },
    someGetter: () => privateMutableThing,
  }
}

const builderTwo: ThingBuilder = params => {
  return {
    someProp: "prop",
    someFn: () => {},
    someGetter: () => "A",
  }
}

const extension = (builder: ThingBuilder): ThingBuilder =>
  params => {
    const base = builder(params)

    // some additional stuff

    return {
      // extended version of base
    }
  }

const builderThree = extension(builderOne)


// Usage: No `new` needed.
const thing1 = builderOne(...)
const thing2 = builderTwo(...)
const thing3 = builderThree(...)
```